# update rows after left join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm looking for a way to update some values in a table if they were used in a left join.

I have two tables:

```
table1:
id | name | age | job
1  | john | 31  | 
2  | eric | 25  | 

table2:
id | job | inserted
1  | lawyer | 0
2  | dentist | 1
3  | cop    |  0
```

Then I run the query:

```
UPDATE  table1
LEFT JOIN
        table2
ON      table1.id = table2.id
SET     table1.job = `table2.job`
WHERE   table2.inserted = 0
```

But I want to update the rows from `table2` that were used in the update so they have inserted = 1. This for two reasons 1) to speed up the join and 2) so I can check which rows of `table2` were not used. (The inserts in `table2` happen before `table1`, but the `id`s in `table2` should always be present in `table1` if all cron jobs run okay.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `LEFT JOIN`, since you only want to update rows in `table1` that have a matching row in `table2`. Try:

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.job = t2.job, t2.inserted = 1
WHERE t2.inserted = 0
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/083f8/1)